How to use Stokes expansion method for solving nonlinear Klein-Gordon equation?
A simple nonlinear Klein-Gordon equation can be written as:
$$
\varphi_{tt} - \varphi_{xx} + V'(\varphi) = 0
$$
If we take
$$
\varphi = \Psi(\theta), \qquad \theta = kx - \omega t
$$
then the equation becomes:
$$
\begin{align}
(\omega^2 - k^2) \Psi_{\theta\theta} + V'(\Psi) &= 0 \tag{1} \\
\frac12 (\omega^2 - k^2) \Psi_{\theta}^2 + V(\Psi) &= A \tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
where eq(2) is the result that we take an integral with respect to $\theta$ of eq(1), and $A$ is the constant of integration.
In a textbook (eq 14.10 - eq 14.13 on p.488), a method called Stokes expansion was used to solve the equations. It is said that if $A$ is small enough, and we take that:
$$
V = \frac12 \varphi^2 + \sigma \varphi^4 + \cdots
$$
then we can solve equation (1) and (2) to get the solutions:
$$
\begin{align}
\Psi &= a \cos \theta + \frac18 \sigma a^3 \cos{3\theta} + \cdots \\
\omega^2 - k^2 &= 1 + 3 \sigma a^2 + \cdots \\
A &= \frac12 a^2 + \frac98 \sigma a^4 + \cdots
\end{align}
$$
My question is that how can we get these solutions even if we have the expansion form of $V$?

Here's the textbook mentioned in the question. The OP omitted a few details.

The expansion comes from solving the integral (14.5) for the given special case of $V(\varphi)$

@K.defaoite thanks for your supplementary material
